# Where to learn homotopy theory?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, rational-homotopy-theory

I've discovered recently that homotopy is more powerful than I thought. I have some knowledge about classic homotopy theory on topological spaces and simplicial complexes and very little about homotopy of CW-complexes.
I want to learn about stable homotopy, rational homotopy, motivic homotopy, model categories. What's is the best way to approach all of this material, and which books I could use to achieve it.

Thank you all and sorry if my English is bad or if my question is too silly.

Comment: How to become a homotopy theorist? Go to graduate school and do your Ph.D. in homotopy theory! By the way, I believe that this question is offtopic for the MSE...

Comment: Dear Alberto, a good try might be _Rational homotopy theory and differential forms_ by Morgan and Griffith (disclaimer : I am not an homotopist and have only read a little part of that book). Look at https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781461484677 for the table of contents.

Comment: @Hasek : If you read not only the title but also the body itself, you will see that the question of the OP is a reasonable reference request about how to get introduced to abstract/modern homotopy theory from a classical algebraic topology class. I don't think at all this question is off-topic (until it's a duplicate of course).

Comment: A modern textbook with a strong emphasis on category theory at a rather introductory level is Riehl's "Categorical Homotopy Theory".